# How to relate a billing cost to google resource in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to find how much each resource is costing me in Google Cloud.
When I run the query in BigQuery the data has no information about the resource like its name or id.
For example
I have a VM by the name of myvm with instance id of 1235XXXXX in myproject . How can I find the cost incurred on this vm in a given period.
The vm has not labels set

The query I am running is

`select *from myproject.mydynaset.gcp_billing_export_v1_786xxxxxxxx`

Comment: Add labels to your resources.

Comment: Is there any other possibility as labels are not mandatory.

Comment: No, labels is the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to know how much will it cost the resources that you're using.